A grid-like cubic graph class with odd cycles
Question: Does a cubic, grid-like graph with many odd cycles exists?
I'm looking for a graph class which is grid like - aka it looks locally the same everywhere. It needs to be cubic and have a lots of odd cycles.
First I thought about taking a graph triangulation of the plane and considering the dual. This did not proved successful. The problem I had was that I could only find triangulations where nodes of $G$ were mostly of degree 6 hence I had cycles of size 6 in $G'$.

Then I tried to force nodes of $G$ to be of odd degrees strictly. This ended with duals where some nodes were of degree 4, hence not cubic.

Then I looked over tilings. I found this article about pentagonal tilings. Page 15, I noticed that the same two problems still appear there: The first figures display actually hexagons (tiles are pentagons but for what I do I would actually consider them as hexagons), or some nodes are actually of degree 4, fourth example in the same line for instance.
At first it seemed like a trivial question but now I'm starting to wonder if a cubic, planar, grid-like graph with many odd cycles exist at all. The planarity of the graph it not necessary for what I need but it would make my work easier.

I'm afraid that what you ask is not quite possible if you are only looking at planar graphs. I'll assume all edges are straight. Gridlike implies that all the faces have the same polygonal shape. But if every vertex is of degree 3, then the average vertex angle is 120 degrees. Therefore the face polygon also has the average angle of 120 degrees, which makes it a hexagon. So either you have to allow more than one type of face shape (some with fewer than 6 sides, some with more, e.g. mixing pentagons and heptagons), or go non-planar.

@JaapScherphuis I should give more details about what I mean by grid-like; regular polygons are not really required. I meant easy to reproduce for as long as we need.

I'm not talking about regular polygons, just polygons that are all of the same shape, or even all with the same number of sides (and about the same area) regardless of shape. All I'm using is that the total of the vertex angles of an n-gon is 180*(n-2).

6+6=5+7
Think of two congruent regular hexagons sharing an edge. Label the vertices A through J in rotational order starting at one of the bridgeheads, so that the shared edge runs from A to F. Now redraw this edge from A to E or from A to G, rather than from A to F. This gives a pentagon-heptagon pair, which may then be tiled periodically (in the same manner as the original hexagon-hexagon pair) to give the desired graph.
6+6=9+3
A higher symmetry structure can be built using a regular enneagon as the starting point. Select any of the three sets of three points that form an equilateral triangle and pull them radially outwards until their angles are reduced to 120° (originally 140°) and the remaining angles become 150°. When the enneagons are then tiled by placing 120° angles from three of them together at one node, they leave gaps which are then filled with equilateral triangles. This result is graphically equivalent to the first case except that the bridging edge would be shifted to AC or AI rather than AE or AG.
